# Bootstrap columns uneven after adding vertical border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added a vertical column to the right of two of my columns (of which there are three) and now **the columns images are different sizes** and when the browser window is resized they **no longer even show on the same line**!

Can anyone tell me why?

Live link: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

Thanks,

Sam

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1">
            <div class="rightborder">
           <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      </div>
         </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-2.png" alt="button-1">
        <div class="rightborder">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Going</b> travelling?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rightborder {
padding-right:30px;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Your images are defined to take 100% width, and as you have `padding-right:30px`, naturally your images will have 30px less width than the div without that padding. First I can think of is CSS your third image (the one that is bigger) with `width: calc(100% - 30px);` About the issue that they are not on the same line, that is because the text above take different amount of lines in each column. You could try defining a fixed `height` for those `<p>` elements

Comment: There are lots of workarounds for your problem, once you got why that is happening you just have to play with your column div's paddings and your `rightborder` paddings

Comment: Thanks, perhaps there is a better way for me to add in the vertical lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this solution. I think it's cleaner than the two previous answers.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1">
            <div class="box-content">
           <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600?random" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      </div>
         </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-2.png" alt="button-1">
        <div class="box-content column-border">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600?random" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1">
       <div class="box-content">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Going</b> travelling?</p>
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600?random" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">   
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-content.column-border{
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Hope I save your life :)

Comment: Boom shackawawa! Thank-you sir! Spot on! If I could give you extra reps I would!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding just

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1">
           <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
         </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 columnBorder"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-2.png" alt="button-1">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1">
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Going</b> travelling?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
columnBorder {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Boom, I hadn't thought of this. Elegant. Thank-you!

Comment: There is one issue. What if I want the border to only start after the numbered images? Since it's on the entire middle div it covers the lot?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">    
  <h3 class="h3big">What do you need help with?</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-1.png" alt="button-1">
            <div>
           <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Living</b> paycheque to paycheque?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
      </div>
         </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-2.png" alt="button-1">

 <!-- You can adjust the position of this Div -->
 <div class="columnBorder"> 
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
 </div>
 <!-- End of the Adjustable Div -->

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/button-3.png" alt="button-1">

      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Going</b> travelling?</p>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You just put the class which is setting border to the left and the right to the middle element.
And, if you want the number to be out of the border, apply the class only on the containing `div` element.

```
columnBorder {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You can adjust to your needs by setting the inner content of the div.
ie:

```
 <!-- You can adjust the position of this Div -->
 <div class="columnBorder"> 
      <p class="alltextbig text-uppercase"><b>Saving</b> to buy a home?</p>
 </div>
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
 <!-- End of the Adjustable Div -->
```